# Why I cannot create a database for graphite-web?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, graphite

I am trying to install `graphite-web` on my computer by following the instructions on
https://gist.github.com/surjikal/2777886. When I try to populate the database with `manage.py syncdb` it does not find a proper database throwing the following error:

```
> sudo python manage.py syncdb
OperationalError: FATAL:  database "/opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db" does not exist
```

Here you can find my database configuration from `local_settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '/opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'graphite',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5678'
    }
}
```

Postgres is running properly:

```
sudo service --status-all | grep postgres 
...
[ + ]  postgresql
```

**Why `manage.py syncdb` cannot create / find the graphite.db file?**

Comment: If you are using postgresql then database path will not be required. You just need database name.

Comment: @anuragal: Thank you - it solved the problem! :)
Please add your comment as an answer that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using postgresql then database path will not be required. You just need database name. like

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'graphite',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'graphite',
    'PASSWORD': '<password>',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5678'
    }
}
```